# GAE session doesn't work?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, session

My project works well in debug mode, but it doesn't work well when I deploy on gae. It seems something is wrong about the session?

The key java and jsp are listed below:

NewStudInfoServlet.java

```
public class NewStudInfoServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    if (req.getParameterValues("StuFirName") != null
            && req.getParameter("StuFirName") != ""
            ) {

            Stud stud = new Stud();
            stud.setFirstName(req.getParameter("StuFirName"));              

            req.getSession().setAttribute("NewStud", stud); 
            req.getSession().setAttribute("StuInfoPage", "NewStudSchoolInfo");
            req.getSession().setAttribute("NewLackInfo", "successful!");                
        } else {
        req.getSession().setAttribute("StuInfoPage", "NewStudInfo");
        req.getSession().setAttribute("NewLackInfo", "First name, Last name, Graduation Year is required");
    }
    resp.sendRedirect("/NewAlumni.jsp");
```

NewAlumni.jsp

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <%@include file='WEB-INF/Header.jsp'%>
    <%
        if (session.getAttribute("StuInfoPage") != null
                && session.getAttribute("StuInfoPage").toString() == "NewStudSchoolInfo") {
    %>
    <%@include file='WEB-INF/NewStudSchoolInfo.jsp'%>       
    <%
        } else {
    %>
    <%@include file='WEB-INF/NewStudInfo.jsp'%>
    <%
        }
    %>
```

In debug mode, it works well: the user fill in the first name and press the button submit,and then the NewAlumni.jsp will include WEB-INF/NewStudSchoolInfo.jsp to let the user submit more information;

However, after I deploy the app in GAE, it works differently. After the user fill in the first name and press the button submit, the NewAlumni.jsp continually includes WEB-INF/NewStudInfo.jsp rather than WEB-INF/NewStudSchoolInfo.jsp. I am sure

```
req.getSession().setAttribute("NewStud", stud); 
req.getSession().setAttribute("StuInfoPage", "NewStudSchoolInfo");
req.getSession().setAttribute("NewLackInfo", "successful!");
```

are executed because I can see the damn "successful!" in NewStudInfo.jsp.

What's wrong? Need your help.

I ready set up true in appengine-web.xml

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check String equality with equals not the == operator. Change
`session.getAttribute("StuInfoPage").toString() == "NewStudSchoolInfo"`
to
`session.getAttribute("StuInfoPage").toString().equals("NewStudSchoolInfo")`

Comment: That's the reason! Thank you!! But why it worked in debug mode even I use session.getAttribute("StuInfoPage").toString() == "NewStudSchoolInfo" ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled HTTP sessions by adding `<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>` to your appengine-web.xml file, as decribed in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Enabling_Sessions)?